# Can one use a gold cup at the Seder?

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, four-cups-wine

I had read somewhere, a few years ago, that one should not use a gold cup for the 4 cups of wine at the Seder. I don't recall the source but I recall that the reason mentioned is that it is considered "pompous".

If someone can confirm or deny this rule from a source, I appreciate it. I'd be surprised if using a gold cup is forbidden as IIRC, the Shulchan Aruch mentions that the Seder table should be set with the finest and nicest things that people own, so why not use a gold cup? Related to this, perhaps, is that the Torah says that Israel left Egypt with gold and silver. So, wouldn't using a gold cup on the Seder be a way of commemorating what occurred?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Kovetz Bais Aharon V'Yisrael note 20 in the center](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13540&st=&pgnum=122&hilite=) the earlier Stoliner Rabbi used a gold cup for the Seder.